# Why my empty program has too many unused imports?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pelles-c

I'm working with *`Visual Studio 2012 & 2017 with C++ 11`* and *`Pelles C 9.0 with C++ 11`*...

When I build **a empty program and DLL** but they contain lots of unused imports in pe file!

**VC++** has **26 imports of KERNEL32** and **Pelles** has **70 imports of KERNEL32**
My project is totally empty!

I need to remove them from linker and compiled file.

I have an **DLL is compiled with Pelles C** and it only has **4 import** that it really use :

```
    KERNEL32.dll
    VirtualProtect  ord:0 rva2iat: 000012A0
    GetModuleHandleA  ord:0 rva2iat: 000012A8
    Sleep  ord:0 rva2iat: 000012B0
    CreateThread  ord:0 rva2iat: 000012B8
```

I want to do the same , I don't need any of those **70 imports** and functions , **How Can I do it ?**

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove them?

Comment: Even if you have an empty `main` function, there's still some code to handle the stuff that's needed before `main` is called, and that cleans up after `main` returns. This is supplied by the compiler, and you shouldn't really build without it unless on smaller embedded systems (where you have your own startup code that then calls `main`).

Comment: As for your problem, what *is* your problem? Why do you need to "remove them"? Remember that a DLL is only loaded *once* and during run-time.

Comment: How are you constructing the project, are you making a windows binary, or are you making a command line exe ? It could make a big difference.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I saw somebody did it and I'm interested how he did it. You know loving pe stuffs :D

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks , No I didn't use even Main , it VC++ I disabled CRT to be able to do that but in PC++ i just compiled a complete empty cpp file [ file size = 0 ] - And I need them becuz I saw somebody did it , I want to know how ....

Comment: @Owl Nah , it's a dll , with no include and no code ... For example I just need VirtualProtect in my dll and nothing more , No need to loadlibrary but it's in my imports...

Comment: "I'd like to learn more about what these bits do" is a different question than "how do I get rid of these bits?"...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe What you suggest ? Hackforums or CheatUnknown ? I think here people have more low-level knowledge !

Comment: I don't believe there's 4 response to **"WHY YOU WANT TO DO THAT"** instead of actually answering to question ....

Comment: Because **you don't want to do that**. The compiler put them there for a reason.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I just did and it works fine ... useless community !

Comment: It's a valid question "why is the bathroom sink compiled into my hello world". I see nothing wrong with that as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **TimoVJL** | Here's the solution :

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:DllMainCRTStartup")
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:_DllMainCRTStartup@12")
#endif
BOOL WINAPI DllMainCRTStartup(HANDLE hDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) g_hmod = hDLL;
    return TRUE;
}
```